# How to use Cloudfront with basic auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I am implementing a cloudfront solution and would like to test / run it on my staging server, however staging is "protected" from the outside world by basic_auth.

I have tried entering a URL with the basic_auth username / password in it e.g user:pass@example-staging.com but CloudFront rejects this URL.

How can I allow Cloudfront / an origin to access my staging server?

(I am hosting on heroku, using rails 4)

Answer (score 14):

Because of the way web content caching works, most HTTP request headers are not forwarded from CloudFront to the origin server by default, including the `Authorization` header needed for basic auth.

You'll need to whitelist the `Authorization` header in the appropriate cache behavior(s).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesWhitelistHeaders

Comment: That was it for me!